# Poetry is asking for me to install 2 dependancies, and each one deletes the others files

Tags: wsl-2, privategpt

I am following NetworkChucks guide on PrivateGPT, he has linked a guide (https://medium.com/@docteur_rs/installing-privategpt-on-wsl-with-gpu-support-5798d763aa31) after getting around some of this issues by coming here and searching i got to the end of the guide and when I try to run private-gpt `make run` it returns with "

```
ImportError: Local dependencies not found, install with `poetry install --extras llms-llama-cpp`
make: *** [Makefile:36: run] Error 1
```

"
so I run `poetry install --extras llms-llama-cpp` then it says I am missing the ui dependencies, but when I run the install it deletes ' --extras llms-llama-cpp' ` Removing llama-cpp-python (0.2.53)

- Removing llama-index-llms-llama-cpp (0.1.3)`

Answer (score 1):

`poetry install --extras "llms-llama-cpp ui"`

This should do it, I just went through this. I threw all my errors into ChatGPT (ironic) and after a bunch of attempts I got it working.